Understanding the definition of left exact functors
I am studying category theory, and in particular exact sequences. I am stuck on proving that the following three conditions are equivalent in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$:
(a) The sequence $0 \to A  \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is exact
(b) The sequence $0 \to \textrm{Hom}(X,A) \xrightarrow{f \circ -} \textrm{Hom}(X,B) \xrightarrow{g \circ -} \textrm{Hom}(X,C)$ is exact for all $X \in \textrm{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$
(c) $A \cong \ker (g)$
Of course, all of these are easily true when we are in the category of modules of a ring $R$, for example, but I am having difficulty showing this in a general abelian category. The difficulty is working with arrows rather than elements of a set.
Here is my work so far, which is an update from a day ago: I have proven the equivalence of (a) and (b). I am left to show that either of these are equivalent to (c).
For part (c), it seems like we would need to use the canonical isomorphism $\textrm{ker(coker}f) \cong \textrm{coker(ker}f)$, but I am not sure how to use this.
My intuition tells me that I am making this way too convoluted than it really is. I would greatly appreciate any proof that is concise and elucidating.

Is there a typo in (c)?

I don't think (c)$\Rightarrow$(a) is true even for abelian groups.  For example, you could have $f = 0$ and $A = \ker(g)$.  Even if $f$ is injective, you could have $g : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}, (a,b) \mapsto a+b$, and $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2, n \mapsto (2n, -2n)$.  Then $\mathbb{Z} \simeq \ker(g)$, but the sequence of $f$ and $g$ is not exact.

@DanielSchepler It is sloppily stated. Really they mean something like, $A\to B$ induces an isomorphism $A\cong\ker g$; and the moral of the story is, in category theory arrows do matter, that's the whole point!! Very often even seasoned authors make this mistake

Or maybe, something such as: $A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} B$ and $\ker(g)$ are isomorphic in the slice category $\mathcal{C}/B$.

@FShrike thank you for your comments. This was from my lecture notes, could you please restate an appropriate modification?

@DanielSchepler also pinning you for the same comment above, as well as a thank you to you also

Let's check $(a)\iff(c)$, and let's more carefully state $(c)$. $A\cong\ker g$ as a standalone statement is sloppy; there's implied context which should be kept explicit in my opinion.
I'm going to talk about "pairs" quite a lot but as commented by Daniel, really I'm thinking about objects in a slice category. If any notation is unclear please ask.
Arrows matter, objects less so; in comments, some examples have already been given. We want $A\cong\ker g$ to "come from" $f$. To be really precise and categorical, $\ker g$ is not just an object. It is in fact the data of a pair $(\mathrm{Ke}(g),\iota)$ where $\iota:\mathrm{Ke}(g)\to B$ is an arrow satisfying a certain universal property that characterises the pair $(\mathrm{Ke}(g),\iota)$ up to isomorphism. In my own handwritten notes, I make a serious effort to emphasise the arrow $\iota=\ker g$ as the important thing distinct from the item $\mathrm{Ke}(g)$.  An alternative perspective which characterises the kernel uniquely up to equality (!!) is as a certain special subobject of $B$. This is cheating slightly however, since subobjects themselves are defined as isomorphism classes. In my humble opinion, there is a fine line between having the mathematical maturity to leave all arrows implicit, unlabelled, suppressing as much notation as possible, and the tempting abyss of sloppily pretending everything commutes and overlooking subtleties (I would contend that even experts do this). Really, many proofs in Abelian category theory and general homological algebra look like they are proofs about objects being isomorphic but are really about arrows being isomorphic, and one must keep track of what is guaranteed by universal properties and what must actually be checked.
Anyway, how would I state $(c)$? I would state it like:

The arrow $f$ is a kernel for $g$

i.e. $(A,f)$ satisfies the universal property of the kernel, $(A,f)\cong(\mathrm{Ke}(g),\ker g)$ as an isomorphism of pairs - simply $A\cong\mathrm{Ke}(g)$ is not good enough - what is that isomorphism? Something abstract, roundabout and nothing to do with $f$? That's no good... we need the isomorphism to be related with $f$.
Now we've got the correct question, let's answer it. Exactness of the sequence at $B$ is by definition equivalent to the existence of an isomorphism of pairs (or an equality of subobjects, "sub" being the key player) $(\mathrm{Im}(f),\mathrm{im}f:\mathrm{Im}(f)\hookrightarrow B)\cong(\mathrm{Ke}(g),\ker g)$. Exactness at $A$ is fairly easily equivalent to $f$ being a monomorphism, in which case the image of $f$ is identifiable with $f$ itself. So it boils down to: $(a)$ iff. $f$ is a monomorphism and $(A,f)\cong(\mathrm{Ke}(g),\ker g)$ but this is just iff. $(c)$, since $\ker g$ is always a monomorphism and this extra condition is redundant.
I don't want to give the wrong impression - if you know what you're doing, it is usually fine not to think too much about isomorphism of pairs and conceptually think more about the objects, since typically your proof would make it clear you get an isomorphism of arrows. However it is still important to keep track of this, and I would say that one of the main insights of category theory is that arrows matter far, far more than objects and we should focus on this if we want to move away from point-set based thinking.
